# Is there way to set key Type and Value Type with CacheConfiguration through spring XML bean configuration

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Just exploring around usage of gridgain cache, trying to create a sample cache using spring XML configuration. Looking to set key type and value type for cache as below which is ofcourse not working.

```
<bean id="cache" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
<property name="name" value="TestCache"/>
<property name="keyType" value = "java.lang.String"/>
<property name="valueType" value = "java.lang.String"/>
</bean>
```

I wanted to set type of key and value with CacheConfiguration bean configuration

Answer (score 1):

To use a cache as a key-value store, you don't need to specify the key- or value type.

If you want to add SQL support to the cache, you can use [Query Entities](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/SQL/sql-api#query-entities) to define column types.